# Multiple plotting operations with d_plyr

Tags: r, plot, dplyr, plyr

I discovered plyr and was playing with an example but could not understand why it does not work: I have a data frame of 10 (x,y) coordinates and want to plot these points one after the other

```
## Creating the data
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10),b=rnorm(10))
## Empty plot
plot(0, xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2))
## Function to be repeated
plot.pts <- function(x){
points(x$a,x$b)
}
## Magic d_plyr
d_ply(df,plot.pts)
```

But I get the error

```
Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : 
no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"
```

I understood d_ply is the function to be used in that case, hence what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will have same result using : `plot.pts(df)`

Comment: of course, but that is not the point, I want to play with d_ply in a way I can easily make out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not really dividing the dataframe into groups based on variables, just calling a function for each row, I think `a_ply` suits better than `d_ply`:

```
a_ply(df,.margins = 1, .fun = plot.pts)
```

In your original `d_ply` call you passed your function where the `.variables` argument that tells `d_ply` how to group the data was supposed to be, giving you that error.

Comment: Thanks Marius, what is the meaning of .margin = 1? I could not find that option in http://nicercode.github.io/2014-02-13-UNSW/lessons/40-repeating/

Comment: @XavierPrudent Dataframes have two dimensions, rows and columns. Supplying `.margins = 1` tells `a_ply` to work along the rows, instead of along the columns.

Comment: do you mean that .margins = 2 would apply the function along the columns?